# Adding <th>'s to Vaadin Grid Dynamically

Tags: polymer, vaadin, vaadin-grid

When adding columns dynamically how can I set the `<th>`'s in a grids header.

```
 <vaadin-grid id="grid">
         <table>
          <colgroup>
          </colgroup>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>adfdfa</th>
              <th>adfdfa</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </vaadin-grid>


  _addCols: function() {
    var inputs = this.selectedForm.inputs;
    var grid = this.$.grid;
    grid.columns = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      var input = inputs[i];
      grid.addColumn({name: input.$key}, i); 
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter found this in the docs.

```
 grid.header.getCell(0, 0).content = 'Project Name';
```

[Documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/elements/vaadin-grid/vaadin-grid-headers.html)